# Changing of site's address in dns cache

Tags: linux, windows, dns, ip

I have one very important for me question, and I cannot find any info about it here or in the internet (the only thing I see is flushing or clearing dns cache). I need to change the address of one site, to the local file, only on my PC(Windows or Linux). As I know dns cache stores adsress to faster connection, so is there a way to change this data? (Maybe powershell/bash or something?) Than you.

Comment: Edit your /etc/hosts file and add the ip-url pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Linux and Windows have a file called hosts which can contain mapping from DNS entry to IP address. The entries in this file will be checked first and take precedence over the external DNS.

```
Windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Linux: /etc/hosts
```